# How do you calculate the expected value of $E\left\{e^{-|X|}\right\}$ e.g. for Gaussian X?

Tags: expected-value, moment-generating-function, folded-normal-distribution

If $X$ is a random variable, I would like to be able to calculate something like $$E\left\{e^{-|X|}\right\}$$
How can I do this, e.g., for a normally distributed $X$?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3790573/321264.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the MGF equation of [Folded Normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution) distribution with $t=-1$.

Comment: Hm. How does this work for negative moments? Wouldn't you need to differentiate the MDF (-1) times and then evaluate at zero?

Comment: Couldn't understand. I was trying to exploit the formula of MGF to find the expected value we want, not aiming to find any moments.

Comment: The MGF *is* used to find moments: we can find $E(|X|^k)$ by taking the $k$-th derivative of the MFG and evaluating at $t=0$. But this only works for $k\geq 0$. How would you use the MGF for $k=-1$, as here? (Is "$t=-1$" a typo?)

Comment: But, The MGF is $E[e^{tY}]$. If we have the expression for general $t$, we can find $E[e^{-Y}]$ by substituting $t=-1$. (assuming $Y$ is folded normal in the OP)

Comment: Duh. I'm sorry. You are right. I had the idea the OP was asking about $E(|X|^{-1})$. Sorry. Forget I asked.